# Continuous integration servers for Flex

Tags: apache-flex, continuous-integration

Which CI server do you use for Flex? My main contenders are currently

- Hudson
- TeamCity

Both seem to be popular on the general level but have you got some direct experience with using one or both with Flex development? Or would you recommend some other tool?

Answer (score 2):

We use Hudson.

We are working on a Java/Flex application.
Ant is the build system. SVN the source manager.

We have a ant task for compiling the mxml and the actionScript.

Hudson is on a virtual machine, SVN on another, and the build are archived / deployed on a third.

Hudson call the ant task on due time. ( After each commit on the flex code )

No Unit test are call for flex. For java yes. But you can call FlexUnit ( or FlexMonkey ) throught a ant script as well.

After running the test, the build is deployed on another VM.

It's run with no pain. You just have to have a working ant task for compilling the flex part of your application.

If your using maven, hudson handle it too. He can also play .bat or .sh script and check the output.

About your choice between teamcity / hudson, i think the two of them are very close.

Answer (score 2):

We use Hudson in combination with SVN and it works quite well. Both the Java code and the Flex code is built using Maven and the [Flex Mojos](http://code.google.com/p/flex-mojos/) plugin. The build also runs the unit tests for the Flex code and it integrates the results in the build reports. The Flex Mojos plugin makes this really easy.

Comment: Agree with Christophe here!

We use the same configuration here and it works like a charm

Comment: Yep we've used this exact setup on several projects.