# Continuous Integration for Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, version-control, hudson, cruisecontrol

My team wants to set up a continuous integration server for a flex 4 project that we are developing. I have been evaluating various options and have some questions.

1. Really torn between Cruise Control and Hudson/Jenkins. [Continuous integration servers for Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048241/continuous-integration-servers-for-flex) shows at least two successful installations of Hudson for Flex.
2. Which source control should we use? I am personally inclined towards GIT, but looks like SVN has a lot more in-built support in both CC and Hudson.
3. In the worst case scenario, we might be forced to use VSS. What is the support for VSS like?

Regards,
Ravi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, NEVER USE VSS.  Biggest POS out there.  Cruise Control/Hudson/Bamboo/Teamcity/etc are just build servers, but they need something to build with like Ant or Maven.  After the build is done, they normally deploy whatever was created to your place of choosing.  Any one of them will work just fine unless you have some *very* specific requirements.

As for version control, all of them can be used with the build server so it comes down to preference.  In a team environment, I prefer Git; however, it is a bit more 'complex' to use than subversion, so training might be involved.  But trust me, a lot less headaches merging with Git than subversion.

The most important part of the whole equation is your Ant or Maven build file.  I personally recommend using Maven over Ant since the dependency management is wonderful for larger projects.  You'll also want to take a look at the [FlexMojos](http://code.google.com/p/flex-mojos/) project to compile/test your Flex application.

Comment: +1  I use Hudson with SVN,Git,Mecurial (based on project) and Ant to build.  Works great.  You can even run your unit test... just make sure your test runner is an Air proj instead of a Flash proj so that it can get pass/fail status via the command line.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot about Mecurial.  Thanks for the reminder Brian.  You don't have to have the test runner in Air, you can get the same result if your build server has Flash Projector installed.  Adobe should really work on a 'no-ui' testing tool however.

Comment: Agree here, never use VSS. It simply is not a proper VCS - it is a simple repository, nothing more, lacking even the most basic VCS features.  I prefer distributed VCS, so I would tend to go with git, but I frequently use SVN which is also quite good.  git vs SVN is less cut and dry - use what is appropriate to your team and their skills.  I definitely suggest Hudson over CC.  Hudson isn't perfect, but it is very very nice, and miles better than CC, in my opinion.  The live ajax console output during builds is simply priceless.  Maven over Ant for me as well.